# Evaluating a form field at a point on vectors in SageMath

Tags: sage

I am having trouble matching up terminology in my textbook (Hubbard's *Vector Calculus*) against SageMath operators. I'd like to understand how to solve the following example problem with Sage:

> Let `phi = cos(x z) dx /\ dy` be a 2-form on `R^3`. Evaluate it at the point `(1, 2, pi)` on the vectors `[1, 0, 1], [2, 2, 3]`.

The expected answer is:

```
cos (1 * pi) * Matrix([1, 2], [0, 2]).det() = -2
```

So far I have pieced together the following:

```
E.<x,y,z> = EuclideanSpace(3, 'E')

f = E.diff_form(2, 'f')
f[1, 2] = cos(x * z)
point = E((1,2,pi), name='point')
anchor = f.at(point)

v1 = vector([1, 0, 1])
v2 = vector([2, 2, 3])

show(anchor(v1, v2))
```

which fails with the error:

> `TypeError: the argument no. 1 must be a module element`

To construct a vector in `E`, I tried:

```
p1 = E(v1.list())
p2 = E(v2.list())
show(anchor(p1, p2))
```

but that fails with the same error. What's the right way to construct two vectors in `E`?

Comment: No definition of `res` is provided. Is `res` the same as `anchor`?

Comment: The vectors need to be based at `point`, i.e. they need to be in the tangent space at `point`.

Comment: Also asked at [Ask Sage question 56483](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/56483).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there.

To evaluate the 2-form at point `p`,
use vectors based at `p`.

```
sage: T = E.tangent_space(point)
sage: T
Tangent space at Point point on the Euclidean space E

sage: pv1 = T(v1)
sage: pv2 = T(v2)
sage: pv1
Vector at Point point on the Euclidean space E
sage: pv2
Vector at Point point on the Euclidean space E

sage: anchor(pv1, pv2)
-2
```